# uk visit visa application dependent question?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas, applications

i stay at parents home with them but i am INdependent financially at home as i do my job and earn income,
me and my parents are applying uk visit visa and father will be paying the trip cost of himself me and mothet.
So now am i his dependent in his application or not ? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, if you pay towards the household expenses. Possibly, if you do not.  The fact that your father is paying for your trip does not of itself mean you are his dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I applied as independent, though my father will be paying for trip , i have my job etc, all three visitor visas got approved for mother father and me in June 2019.